# IPValidator Extension: Path is invalid

Tags: yii

I'm trying to use the [ipvalidator](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/ipvalidator/) extension for Yii and have installed it as instructed under `/protected/extensions/`. I then added the following rule to my model:

```
array('ipAddress', 'application.extensions.ipvalidator.IPValidator', 'version' => 'v4'),`
```

I am now getting the following error:

```
Alias "application.extensions.ipvalidator.IPValidator" is invalid. Make sure it points to an existing PHP file.`
```

Is there something I have done wrong here?

Comment: You sure cAsE of folder is same? Cant think of anything other wrong here. Path should be `protected/extensions/ipvalidator/` and this folder should contain file `IPValidator.php`, thats it. It has nothing to do with this particular extension, Yii just can't find path to `IPValidator`. You can try `var_dump(realpath(Yii::getPathOfAlias('<yourPathHere>')));`

Comment: @PeterM I tried to do the var_dump and got the following path: `/var/www/inventory/web/inventory/protected/extensions/ipvalidator`. This is the correct path though. I don't see why it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

```
array('ip', 'match', 'pattern'=>'/^(([1-9]?[0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([1-9]?[0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$/','message'=>'IP not valid')
```

Actually its all that extension. And your problem is wrong path.

Comment: What is wrong with the path, and what is wrong with the extension?

Comment: Make sure it points to an existing PHP file. - it doesnt see IPValidator.php at path that you give. And for the extension - it can be rewritten in 1 line in rules, which i gave you. Its kinda useless.

Comment: Well the problem is that I am looking to check for ipV4 or ipV6 depending on what the address looks like. Using one of the comments code on the extensions page I am able to modify the extension to do this. Along with that, if you look in the comments the path does appear to be correct, yet doesn't work.